# WCF attribute Required annotation

Tags: wcf, xsd, xmlserializer

I build a WCF service with [XmlSerializerFormat] infrastructure. Each model component has multiple attributes ([XmlAttribute] annotations). How can i mark as required for "string" attributes in definition XSD.

Current model sample:

```
public partial class Header1Type : HeaderType
{
    private string mSRefIdField;

    private string sSNRefIdField;

    private StatusCodeEnumType statusCodeField;

    private string statusMessageField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string MSRefId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mSRefIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.mSRefIdField = value;
        }
    }



    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string SSNRefId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sSNRefIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sSNRefIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public StatusCodeEnumType StatusCode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.statusCodeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.statusCodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string StatusMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return this.statusMessageField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.statusMessageField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Current wsdl definition:

```
<xs:complexType name="Header1Type">
<xs:complexContent mixed="false">
<xs:extension base="tns:HeaderType">
<xs:attribute name="MSRefId" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="SSNRefId" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="StatusCode" type="tns:StatusCodeEnumType" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="StatusMessage" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I need string attributes to be decorated with use="required"